# Failed to create folders Zipper/laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

I am uploading a zip file which I then need to get extracted at the path with the same file name. So I have used the [Chumper/Zipper](https://github.com/Chumper/Zipper) and to achieve my task I have used the following code i.e.

```
 $zipper->zip('storage/apps/'.$name)->extractTo('storage/apps/'.$name);
```

It throws an error **Failed to create folders** at zipper.php at 534, which states, i.e.,

```
`if (!$this->file->exists($dir) && !$this->file->makeDirectory($dir, 0755, true, true)) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('Failed to create folders');`
```

I figured out that there must a permission issue, so I did

> sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/admin-panel/public/storage/apps/

Still got the same error, so I again tried the above command with 777 which is both read/write in the parent directory.

Still, the issue is not resolved.

Help will be appreciated. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Are your sure, you have created "apps" folder in the storage directory? Laravel generates the folder named "app" by default.

Comment: Maybe you didn't notice that I am not giving path from the root so I am in public directory as('storage/apps') so there is also a storage folder inside public and then a custom apps folder

Comment: Did you tried this way
 $zipper->zip('public/storage/apps/'.$name)->extractTo('public/storage/apps/'.$name);

Comment: laravel base_path directory start from public, no need of putting public as it will create a public folder inside public , sorry but i guess you have to sure about the answer, anyways thanx